# Ethernet and Bluetooth suddenly aren't working after restart

Tags: networking, bluetooth, ethernet, 22.04

I was restarting my computer and when it came on the ethernet and bluetooth didn't show up. I am using same cables and adapters and everything. The lights are still showing up in the ethernet port on my motherboard but Ubuntu isn't showing that ethernet is connected. The Bluetooth adapter is showing up in lsusb but settings shows no Bluetooth adapter is connected.

Used lshw -c network and it shows my port and it shows *-network UNCLAIMED

```
Lspci -knn | grep net -A3, rfkill list

22:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7b79]
26:00.0 USB Controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:1242]
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1462:7b79]
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Did you install some update before rebooting?

Comment: Check if you have updated your kernel to a "too new" branch, try return to the older selecting it at boot.

Comment: I did an apt update and I installed a different Nvidia driver I think that's all

Comment: I was looking and it seems like other people have had problems after doing an apt-get update and that's what I did, how do I reverse it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Kernel is not fully installed. Probably an upgrade was interrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Network should work. Then upgrade the system by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

It looks like an upgrade was interrupted. And a part of the kernel didn't install.